# Apache directory listing - force show files first (in the same way as FoldersFirst)

Tags: apache, mod-autoindex

I'd like to display an a-z list of files above and a-z list of folders. Without +FoldersFirst the listing is obviously an a-z mixed list of files and folders.

Is there such a thing that can display an equivalent to a 'FilesFirst' directive? I can't see anything in the current mod_autoindex module so am I grasping at straws?

Current code is:

IndexOptions +Charset=UTF-8 +FancyIndexing +IgnoreCase +XHTML +HTMLTable +SuppressRules +SuppressDescription +NameWidth=* +IconsAreLinks